# Drag end not fired when there is a computation heavy task in drag start

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I think I found a bug in Mozilla Firefox 58.0b6. I posted more Detail here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1421333

The main problem is that the dragend event is not fired if the dragstart event is triggered twice before the execution of dragstart listener finishes the first time. 
The problem can be demonstrated with the following code (find the whole example in the fiddle):

```
const dragElement = document.getElementById('drag');

dragElement.addEventListener('dragstart',(e) => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',' ');
  console.log('dragstart');
  let i = 0;
  let result = 0;
  while (i++ < 10000000) {
    result += i * 123 * 34 * 23 / 13;
  }
  console.log('dragstart done ' + result);
});
dragElement.addEventListener('drag',() => console.log('drag'));
dragElement.addEventListener('dragend',() => console.log('dragend'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xhn5rfrn/2/

and a video which describes the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j9SZQja_W239NDWOvLndhxXm4SbILa0d/view

Now my question: how could I create a workaround? Is this even possible or do I have to wait for Firefox to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: mybe hand that off to a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) which runs on a different thread

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the hint, but it's not that easy to refactor everything to work with a Web Worker. It's in the middle of a Three.js application. I think it's even easier to refactor the UI that it works without drag and drop. But this is not ideal :-/